# Django custom command - Not Implemented Error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to set up a cronjob on my Ubuntu server to run a django `.py` file - but I'm having trouble running the script first.

I'm using the command `python3 /opt/mydir/manage.py updatefm`

which produces the error:

```
File "/opt/mydir/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 324, in handle
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

Can anybody enlighten my on what I'm doing incorrect? Here is my script and structure:

```
/mydir
   /mydir
      __init__.py
      /management
         __init__.py
         /commands
            updatefm.py
```

**updatefm.py**

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = ''
    help = 'Help Test'
    def update_auto(self, *args, **options):
        hi = 'test'
```

My app name is listed in `settings.py` as it should be.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `__init__.py` inside your `/commands` directory. Also, I'm not a 100% sure, but I believe you should import said command as well in your `manage.py`

Comment: I think in the documentation it says I only need `__init__.py` in `/commands` directory if i'm using `python2` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands

Comment: `NotImplementedError` means you haven't implemented the full API for a subclass and the parent class can't do it for you. It's being raised by the `handle` method. You don't implement that. Seems like you should.

Comment: @rednaxela, a quote [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) : 
"On Python 2, be sure to include __init__.py files in both the management and management/commands directories as done above or your command will not be detected."

Comment: @Av4t4r I'm using python3

Comment: My bad, I misread your comment (which was confusing me given your stacktrace)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `__init__.py` inside `commands` folder. Then you have to use `handle` method

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = ''
    help = 'Help Test'
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        hi = 'test
```

For more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.handle

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise it actually had to be named `handle()`. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Classes inheriting from `BaseCommand` must implement the method `handle`.

In your case, you should change

`def update_auto(self, *args, **options):`

to

`def handle(self, *args, **options):`